# VBA WORD: Want to get the text in between tags

Tags: vba, ms-word

VBA WORD: Want to get the text in between tags

I want to pull out the text that is in between

```
"<start=" and ">"
```

and make that text all upper case and replace all the space to hyphen on that particular text.

Example:

```
<start="The quick brown fox jumps' over the lazy dog while the cat is running-towards the obstacle_course">The quick brown fox jumps' over the lazy dog while the cat is running-towards the obstacle_course</end>
```

Output must be:

```
<start="THE-QUICK-BROWN-FOX JUMPS'-OVER-THE-LAZY-DOG-WHILE-THE-CAT-IS-RUNNING-TOWARDS-THE OBSTACLE_COURSE">The quick brown fox jumps' over the lazy dog while the cat is running-towards the obstacle_course</end>
```

I used the below codes but it's only applicable up to 10 words(if possible no limits). Is/are there possible/other way/s to do this.

```
With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .MatchWildcards = True
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 .Text = "<start=" & Chr(34) & xVal & "( )" & xVal & "( )" & xVal & "( )" & xVal & "( )" & xVal
 .Replacement.Text = "<start=" & Chr(34) & "\1-\3-\5-\7-\9"
 .Replacement.Font.AllCaps = True
 .Forward = True
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End with
```

TIA
-Sirk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're certain each instance you're looking for begins and ends with **="** and **>**, then you can use this code. You have to select some text first that includes what you're looking for.

```
Private Sub FindStartText()
    Dim findRange As range
    Set findRange = Selection.range

    With findRange.Find
     .ClearFormatting
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .Text = "=""*\>"
    End With
    findRange.Find.Execute

    TextChange findRange
End Sub

Private Sub TextChange(foundRange As range)
    Dim myText As String
    myText = foundRange.Text
    myText = Replace(myText, " ", "-")
    myText = UCase(myText)

    foundRange.Text = myText
End Sub
```